# Page function in R

Tags: r, windows, rstudio

I am trying to print a simple output in R via page, currently at a Windows 10 machine. It worked in the past, now it does not anymore. Windows normally used to ask with which program the file should be opened, but there is no pop up anymore. Anyone else having these issues, or knows how to resolve maybe? Could be related to the latest big Windows update, but does not have to be. I am using Rstudio as IDE.

example:

```
x <- data.frame(matrix(1:9,3,3))
page(x,method="print") # no effect
```

Windows 10 (Home edition), Version: 10.0.18362 Build 18362. In the meantime, updated RStudio to latest version 1.2.1335 (64 bit), R also to the latest version 3.6.1 (64 bit). Problem still occurs.

Edit: Tested with a Windows 7 machine, Rstudio latest version 1.2.1335 (64 bit). Works fine here. Problem seems to be related to Windows 10.

Edit2: Tested with a different Windows 10 (Enterprise edition) machine, Version: 10.0.14393 Build 14393. Here it works fine. Problem seems to be related to the latest version of Windows 10 and/or Home vs Enterprise edition.

Someone mentioned the implementation is system dependent. Here is the Windows implementation:

```
page <-
function (x, method = c("dput", "print"), ...) 
{
  local.file.show <- function(file, title = subx, delete.file = TRUE, 
                              pager = getOption("pager"), ...) file.show(file, 
                                                                         title = title, delete.file = delete.file, pager = pager)
  local.dput <- function(x, file, title, delete.file, pager, 
                         ...) dput(x, file, ...)
  local.print <- function(x, title, delete.file, pager, ...) print(x, 
                                                                   ...)
  if (is.character(x) && length(x) == 1L) {
    subx <- x
    parent <- parent.frame()
    if (exists(subx, envir = parent)) 
      x <- get(subx, envir = parent)
    else stop(gettextf("no object named '%s' to show", 
                       x), domain = NA)
  }
  else {
    subx <- deparse(substitute(x))
  }
  file <- tempfile("Rpage.")
  if (match.arg(method) == "dput") 
    local.dput(x, file, ...)
  else {
    sink(file)
    local.print(x, ...)
    sink()
  }
  local.file.show(file, ...)
}
```

Trying to trace the error by executing the above code line-by-line, I find that the file is correctly created in the Local/Temp folder, but then the remaining code of the function returns no result (tested all different ways). To be more specific, `file.show("C:\\Users\\XYZ\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpOmW06C\\Rpage.1d0562862a6")` just has no effect. The command `file.show` works with other paths. Also I just found out, that once I opened the file manually, I can also use the command afterwards successfully from within RStudio. So it is no authorization error; rather Windows does not ask anymore if the file should be opened if the file type is unknown. Would be nice if someone can confirm.
Any hints highly welcome.

Comment: Is this with RGui, RStudio, Rscript, other? (I'm on R/RStudio/Ubuntu 19.04 and it works as expected.)

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thanks for the question, it is with RStudio

Comment: `page` calls `file.show` and according to the latter function's help page *"How the pager is implemented is highly system-dependent."*

Comment: @RuiBarradas thanks, but this should work with Win 10, shouldn't it? There are a lot of Win users out there and it worked in the past. I am just wondering if the problem is caused by Windows, or by RStudio. Any hints what could be done?

Comment: I can confirm it works on my Win10.  Can you try `page(x,method="dput")` I am on RStudio 1.0.143.

Comment: @Monk thank that's helpful. So likely a problem on my system, even though I did not change RStudio. My version is 1.1.463, so newer than yours? I am pretty sure it doesn't work anymore since I got the "May 2019 Update" for Win 10. `page(x,method="dput")` also has no effect unfortunately.

Comment: What if you restart R in 32 bit (Tools / Global Options) ?

Comment: Have you tried this?
write.csv(mtcars, file = 'a.csv')
file.show('~/a.csv')

Comment: @Monk thanks a lot for your advice. I have tried `write.csv(mtcars, file = 'a.csv');file.show('~/a.csv')` - this works fine. I could not find 32 bit option, but normally 64 bit should be correct for my system; I can still try if you tell me where to find that option.

Comment: I have posted my recommended 'file.show' code as a solution.  If it's working for you, no need to test the 32/64 bit options (I was just trying to determine if bit was related to the issue you were experiencing).

Answer (score 5):

```
write.csv(mtcars, file = 'a.csv'); file.show('~/a.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks, that works nicely. The problem is that it is only a workaround for me, because I do not want to store files on my HD every single time just to show them. I upvoted you for your efforts nontheless.

Comment: @Talik3233 what about following it with `file.remove('a.csv')` or do you not want it stored at all?

Comment: @lazer-guided-lazerbeam thanks, that is a good addition, most of the times I do not want to store it permanently. This solution works, but it is more verbose than a working `page` function. That's why I haven't accepted it. Also I don't think the issue is related just to my Windows system, as I haven't changed anything on my pc really, besides updating from time to time. It is a PC at work, so other causes (e.g. virus etc.) are highly unlikely. The Windows 10 is Home edition, maybe that plays a role as well.